# Designing our database, table structure, relational

Tags: database

So, we are building some sort of a 'debate' game. There are different game types, duel and group discussions, both of them have a couple of defined rules, such as length of the debate, participants limits etc.

```
debates
    id
    title
    body
    created
    modified

   debate_posts
        id
        debate_id
        body
        user_id
        created
        modified

debate_participants
    user_id
    debate_id
```

What I need to know is how can I check when the debate is starting (must be at least two participants) Should I store some timestamp or something similar on when the second one joins?

The second thing I'd like to know is how can I define a winner, should I have a third table, defining the "winner" of a debate, user_id and debate_id?

I'm not quite sure what kind of details I should add to the question, but If there are anything you could provide me with, I would be happy to hear about it.

**Update**

The debaters will be able to make the posts until the time goes out, then there will be other users voting if which users/group wins.

Comment: What actually defines who won?  Also, do you need to keep track of each modification, or just the last?  Your current structure allows only for the last modification to the record.  And picky note:  You use "user_id", but then use just "id" in other tables.  I guess that's a join table?  In an app I'm toying with, I have a similar structure, so beyond those picky things, looks good to me.

Comment: I updated with some details. What do you mean with my structure only allows for the last modification?

Comment: As an aside, table names should be *singular* (or, more precisely, should represent a *row*, so `debate` instead of `debates`).

Comment: What I mean by "only allows for the last modification" I mean "modification time."  So if three changes occur on a given debate_post, then you'll only have the time stamp for the last change.  Which might be fine.

Comment: How are you recording users votes?  I don't see anything in this structure that accommodates votes.  That would have implications on how to record a winner.

Comment: @Marvo That is what I am trying to figure out as well

Comment: Are the voters going to be users, too?  How will you ensure that a given person only votes once?  (Tough regardless of how you do it on the internets.)  If each debate_post can be voted on, then another table called debate_post_vote might contain (voter_id_or_IP_addr, debate_post) and that should cover it.  If you vote on the person, then it'd probably be debate(voter_id, user_id).  Then count the records in those tables per debate or post.

Comment: Yes, the users will be voters, however users may only vote on certain type of debates, such as the group discussion debate, the other debate should be decided by a judge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine you'd need a timestamp of when the second participate joins to know when the debate started. Anytime a user joins a debate query debate_participants to see how many distinct users are in that particular debate and if there is one, then the new participant will be the second and set the start timestamp in debates.

Another way to find out when the debate started would to be to find the earliest time that a post was made in the debate by a second user in the debate_posts table.

To define a winner, if there is at most one winner, you could just add a winner_id field to debates that is the key to wherever you store users.

Comment: Depending on the debate type, it could vary between one or many winners.

Comment: I personally wouldn't add a winner_id field to the debate table because then you start using "null" as an indication that no winner has been decided.  I hate using nulls in general, and less so when it determines state.  But that might be a personal choice.

Comment: To handle multiple users and to update who is currently winning, you could keep a votes table that has as its field: voter_id and voted_for_id (not sure of the best name for this field). You could then retrieve that top N debaters in the debate by counting the number of votes for voted_for_id and limiting it to the top N.

Comment: Well sure, but is there way to properly differ the way of voting, let's say there are TWO different way of winning, one is by "users" voting on, well let's say posts on a current debate, and the second one is by, let's say like 2-5 users? I guess I need a way to tell what debate it is, and someway to tell which one these new users vote on, am I right?